# Java Builder pattern

Tags: java, standards, builder

I recently wrote a builder class and noticed that the standard seems to be as follows

```
public class PersonBuilder {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public PersonBuilder withFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public PersonBuilder withLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public Person build() {
        return new Person(this);
    }
}
```

Is there any disadvantage to, instead, doing the following

```
public class PersonBuilder {
    private Person person;

    public PersonBuilder withFirstName(String firstName) {
        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        return this;
    }

    public PersonBuilder withLastName(String lastName) {
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        return this;
    }

    public Person build() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

I understand this may be an opinion based question, I was just looking for any answers as to why this may be a bad or better design pattern.

Comment: Yes in a concurrent system this can lead to inconsitency. One thread would modify the first name as something and the other can override it and the first thread gets the same object with a different first name than what it has set

Comment: If you call `build` twice you don't get two different objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach. Some of them are described in previous answers so I'll just mention the others.

The biggest problem with your design, is that you're using a single instance of `Person` in the builder. This means that if you're using the same builder more than once, you'll be "building" the same instance, while the clients using it are expecting two different instances. No need to mention that this could cause some serious havoc in your application.

The answer you got from @Basilevs mentions that the "built" class will require setters. This is absolutely true, but I'd just like to stress that this is a huge problem, since it means that the classes you "build" can **never** be immutable ! In other words, you're restricting the implementers of such classes to using synchronization for thread safety if needed, and other problem solving mechanisms that could have been avoided using the common approach.

Comment: If setters have limited visibility, we can avoid synchronization by carefully managing writeable interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

- Builder can be used when there is no setters in the class being built.
- Accepting builder as constructor argument introduces tight coupling.

Following approach solves these:

```
public class PersonBuilder {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public PersonBuilder withFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public PersonBuilder withLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public Person build() {
        return new Person(firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that it can't be used when there are setters and getters?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils There is no need for builder if every field is writable.

Comment: what about if you have a class with 40 fields, you would need a very large constructor for the Person class, no?

Comment: @JonathanViccary Nope, [Parameter object](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/145055/are-there-guidelines-on-how-many-parameters-a-function-should-accept) pattern will solve this.

Comment: That seems a little redundant. You'd essentially be building a Person to pass into the constructor of a Person to build that Person. Why not just build the person and return it?

Comment: @JonathanViccary do you really think that a class with forty fields is ok and should not be refactored to two or three (at least) smaller chunks?

Comment: Thats entirely dependent on the context. Generally best practice would  call for smaller objects, business objects should certainly be smaller. But consider the question here, one instance in which we may have forty fields would be some data table using NoSQL, like DynamoDB, which doesn't necessarily need refactoring, or perhaps some denormalized JDBC database. In this case, and indeed in any other case, your suggestion for building using the parameter pattern isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is there any disadvantage to, instead, doing the following
```

Yes, by the time the user call the `withFirstName` method it will result to `NPE` because you did not even instantiate person.

Comment: I'm assuming he would instantiate person in the constructor of `PersonBuilder`.

Comment: @Eran true2x, just pointing out what it might happen. If there is no constructor that will instantiate it.